# Pandas Groupby Min and Max of last N rows of a column

Tags: python, pandas

A time series data has 3 columns apart from index, which is time

```
indexTime,A,B,C
```

I want to list all As that have last 10 B and C +ve

This means I have to do a

```
groupby('A')
```

and then have an AND condition for

```
last N rows of B.min() > 0 AND last N rows of C.min() > 0
```

How do I do it ?

```
09:00,ABC,1,1
09:00,XYZ,15,2
09:01,ABC,2,4
09:01,XYZ,1,2
09:02,ABC,-1,2
09:02,XYZ,1,7
09:03,ABC,3,5
09:03,XYZ,5,2
```

let us say last 3
in this case XYZ would satisfy the condition as it has both B and C column last 3 rows positive where as ABC does not have all last 3 rows positive

Column B of ABC 09:02 is -1 so it would fail the test even though column C of ABC is all positive. But because of AND condition it would fail

Thus for the condition output would be XYZ as only that satisfies the condition

Comment: Can you add some sample and desired output?

Comment: Added some sample data

Comment: ANd desired output ?

Comment: Added output also. In this case XYZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) and [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True`s:

```
a = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: (x.tail(3) > 0).all(1))
print (a)
     09:01  09:02  09:03
A                       
ABC   True  False   True
XYZ   True   True   True

b = a.index[a.all(1)]
print (b)
Index(['XYZ'], dtype='object', name='A')
```

---

```
print (a)
A        ABC   XYZ
09:01   True  True
09:02  False  True
09:03   True  True

b = a.columns[a.all()].tolist()
print (b)
['XYZ']
```

Comment: What is x ? Header is A,B,C only

Comment: It is name of variable in `lambda` function.

Comment: It is same like `a = df.groupby('A').apply(f)`, `def f(x): print (x) return (x.tail(3) > 0).all(1)`

Comment: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: 0.20.3 and python 2.7

Comment: timeIndex is a column. You have show it as a row in your example

Comment: So first need `a = df.set_index('timeIndex').groupby('A').apply(lambda x: (x.tail(3) > 0).all(1))`

Comment: a is working. problem is with b. it is giving axis problem with b. Note your a has true/false horizontal. mine is coming vertical

Comment: So columns are `ABC, XYZ` and index is `09:01  09:02  09:03` ?

Comment: Ok, then need `b = a.columns[a.all()]`

Comment: but a is evaluated as series. So how can columns be done on it like this?

Comment: Sorry, what Series it return? values are `True` + `False`s and index is `ABC, XYZ` ?

Comment: I get it by `a = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: (x.tail(3) > 0).all(1).all())`

Comment: Yes series ABC,XYZ as index and TRUE/FALSE in the column

Comment: OK, then is is simplier `b = a.index[a]`

Comment: One question, there are other columns also apart from B and C like D,E,F. I don't want to consider them. I think in your case all columns are considered

Comment: So simplier `a = df[['B','C']].groupby('A').apply(lambda x: (x.tail(3) > 0).all(1))`